# Square up form build not populating fields on IOS device in ( Phonegap application )

Tags: javascript, android, ios, phonegap, square

I am working on the square up API. And using the js libraries to populate their form. When I create the build of my application and run it on android it's working fine and populating the form as expected.

But on IOS devices it's not populating the form fields. even the object is created when I alert it

> alert(JSON.stringify(paymentform));

Populating in the same way on IOS and Android.

My code is.

> HTML

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.squareup.com/v2/paymentform"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="sqpaymentform.js"></script>

<div id="pay_now_cc_dialog" style="display: none;">
                            <b>Recipient</b>: Please fill out your credit card information below:<br><br>
                            <form id="nonce-form" novalidate method="post">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" style="height: 38px !important;" name="cc_number"
                                           id="sq-card-number"/>
                                    <small>Credit Card Number</small>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" style="height: 38px !important;" name="cc_expiration"
                                           id="sq-expiration-date"/>
                                    <small>Expiration Date</small>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" style="height: 38px !important;" name="cc_cvv" id="sq-cvv"/>
                                    <small>CVV Code</small>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" style="height: 38px !important;" name="cc_zip"
                                           id="sq-postal-code"/>
                                    <small>ZIP Code</small>
                                </div>
                                <button id="sq-creditcard" class="button-credit-card" onclick="requestCardNonce(event)">
                                    Charge Card
                                </button>

                                <!--
                                  After a nonce is generated it will be assigned to this hidden input field.
                                -->
                                <input type="hidden" id="card-nonce" name="nonce">
                            </form>
                        </div>
```

> JS Code

```
/*
 * function: requestCardNonce
 *
 * requestCardNonce is triggered when the "Pay with credit card" button is
 * clicked
 *
 * Modifying this function is not required, but can be customized if you
 * wish to take additional action when the form button is clicked.
 */
function requestCardNonce(event) {

    // Don't submit the form until SqPaymentForm returns with a nonce
    event.preventDefault();

    // Request a nonce from the SqPaymentForm object
    paymentForm.requestCardNonce();
}

// Create and initialize a payment form object
var paymentForm = new SqPaymentForm({

    // Initialize the payment form elements
    applicationId: applicationId,
    locationId: locationId,
    inputClass: 'sq-input',

    // Customize the CSS for SqPaymentForm iframe elements
    inputStyles: [{
        fontSize: '.9em'
    }],

    // Initialize the credit card placeholders
    cardNumber: {
        elementId: 'sq-card-number',
        placeholder: '•••• •••• •••• ••••'
    },
    cvv: {
        elementId: 'sq-cvv',
        placeholder: 'CVV'
    },
    expirationDate: {
        elementId: 'sq-expiration-date',
        placeholder: 'MM/YY'
    },
    postalCode: {
        elementId: 'sq-postal-code',
        placeholder: '-----'
    },

    // SqPaymentForm callback functions
    callbacks: {

        /*
         * callback function: methodsSupported
         * Triggered when: the page is loaded.
         */
        methodsSupported: function (methods) {

            var applePayBtn = document.getElementById('sq-apple-pay');
            var applePayLabel = document.getElementById('sq-apple-pay-label');
            var masterpassBtn = document.getElementById('sq-masterpass');
            var masterpassLabel = document.getElementById('sq-masterpass-label');

            // Only show the button if Apple Pay for Web is enabled
            // Otherwise, display the wallet not enabled message.
            if (methods.applePay === true) {
                applePayBtn.style.display = 'inline-block';
                applePayLabel.style.display = 'none';
            }
            // Only show the button if Masterpass is enabled
            // Otherwise, display the wallet not enabled message.
            if (methods.masterpass === true) {
                masterpassBtn.style.display = 'inline-block';
                masterpassLabel.style.display = 'none';
            }
        },

        /*
         * callback function: createPaymentRequest
         * Triggered when: a digital wallet payment button is clicked.
         */
        createPaymentRequest: function () {

            var paymentRequestJson;
            /* ADD CODE TO SET/CREATE paymentRequestJson */
            return paymentRequestJson;
        },

        /*
         * callback function: cardNonceResponseReceived
         * Triggered when: SqPaymentForm completes a card nonce request
         */
        cardNonceResponseReceived: function (errors, nonce, cardData) {
            if (errors) {
                // Log errors from nonce generation to the Javascript console
                console.log("Encountered errors:");
                var message_string = "";

                errors.forEach(function (error) {
                    message_string = message_string + error.message + ".<br>";
                });

                swal({
                    type: "error",
                    title: "Error Charging Card",
                    html: true,
                    text: message_string,
                    confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
                });

                return;
            }

            // Assign the nonce value to the hidden form field
            console.log(nonce);
            document.getElementById('card-nonce').value = nonce;

            //alert(nonce);
            // POST the nonce form to the payment processing page
            // document.getElementById('nonce-form').submit();
            test_cc();

        },

        /*
         * callback function: unsupportedBrowserDetected
         * Triggered when: the page loads and an unsupported browser is detected
         */
        unsupportedBrowserDetected: function () {
            /* PROVIDE FEEDBACK TO SITE VISITORS */
        },

        /*
         * callback function: inputEventReceived
         * Triggered when: visitors interact with SqPaymentForm iframe elements.
         */
        inputEventReceived: function (inputEvent) {
            switch (inputEvent.eventType) {
                case 'focusClassAdded':
                    /* HANDLE AS DESIRED */
                    break;
                case 'focusClassRemoved':
                    /* HANDLE AS DESIRED */
                    break;
                case 'errorClassAdded':
                    /* HANDLE AS DESIRED */
                    break;
                case 'errorClassRemoved':
                    /* HANDLE AS DESIRED */
                    break;
                case 'cardBrandChanged':
                    /* HANDLE AS DESIRED */
                    break;
                case 'postalCodeChanged':
                    /* HANDLE AS DESIRED */
                    break;
            }
        },

        /*
         * callback function: paymentFormLoaded
         * Triggered when: SqPaymentForm is fully loaded
         */
        paymentFormLoaded: function () {
            console.log("Square loaded");
            /* HANDLE AS DESIRED */
        }
    }
});
```

I think it should work out for both IOS and Android. But only working on Android.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by populating the form? Is it not loading the input fields? Are you able to debug and see the browser console errors? Also, we do have In-App Payments SDK which is basically the payment form built in a mobile application. We don't have a plugin for Phonegap, but you might be interested: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/in-app-payments-sdk/what-it-does

Comment: @sjosey Hi, Populating form means In android it applies the placeholders in the form.
In IOS it's just giving me the fields without placeholders. and the fields are also not editable. and then click on the charge button, square up callback function is not fire.

Comment: @sjosey and in browser console it's showing me the error "Cannot read property 'build' of undefined". But it's working fine in android device.

Comment: Where are you calling `build` from? I don't see it in the above JS code. That's a function on the payment form, but it sounds like it's getting called before the payment form object has been initialized.

Comment: I am calling it on click function. when the user clicks on the credit card payment button. I did alert the object in IOS device and it's returning the complete object as well.

Comment: The click of the buy button? If you're not setting `autoBuild: false` in the initialization (which in your code you are definitely not), then you do not need to call `build()`. I would suggest removing it and seeing if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Thanks. let me check. With the same code, it's working on Android, strange.

Comment: @sjosey did not work. :-(

Comment: @sjosey it is applying only the style class to the fields. Even it's not editable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191286/discussion-between-sjosey-and-shaban).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting answer over here for everyone else:

In your config.xml file, you need to add

```
<allow-navigation href="https://*squareup.com/*" />
```

Based from https://medium.com/collaborne-engineering/who-blocks-my-youtube-embed-cordova-phonegap-45a8ec04ff72